# ggplot2 and first data point in a line

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am creating two plots using `ggplot2` and then using `grid.arrange` to merge them together. I should say that both of the plots are also using `facet_grid` for a visual tweaking.

[image]

My problem is that the bottom plot, which is really a data table, ends up being "cut off" on the BOTH the left and right sides because of the starting position and ending positions for the facets. Is there a way for me to tweak this? I would like to tweak this so the points are not getting cut off.

Here is the data to reproduce it:

```
   df <- structure(list(SurveyID = c(16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 26L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L
), MEPSID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), ServiceID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("Army", "Navy", "Marines", "Air Force"
), class = "factor"), SurveyReturnedYear = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 
2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2014L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 
2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L), SurveyReturnedMonth = c(10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), CompletedSurvey = c(23L, 19L, 38L, 16L, 11L, 
16L, 38L, 19L, 6L, 14L, 41L, 10L, 6L, 32L, 46L, 18L, 12L, 30L, 
35L, 18L, 11L, 32L, 23L, 19L, 8L, 24L, 46L, 19L, 18L, 28L, 30L, 
19L, 12L, 27L, 32L, 15L, 20L, 31L, 34L, 26L, 30L, 25L, 26L, 17L, 
41L, 16L, 24L, 12L, 43L, 23L, 22L, 15L, 29L, 21L, 22L, 18L, 38L, 
10L, 20L, 13L, 46L, 19L, 19L, 9L, 32L, 10L, 17L, 27L, 31L, 21L, 
17L, 18L, 30L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 17L, 17L, 34L, 21L, 16L, 
4L, 34L, 29L, 20L, 18L, 25L, 21L, 24L, 19L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 13L, 
28L, 19L, 24L, 0L, 23L, 13L, 13L, 2L, 34L, 13L, 22L, 4L, 17L, 
26L, 5L, 17L, 27L, 18L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 11L, 34L, 0L, 27L, 9L, 
34L, 0L), TotalSurvey = c(41L, 19L, 47L, 22L, 43L, 21L, 49L, 
23L, 39L, 16L, 44L, 11L, 49L, 34L, 56L, 33L, 39L, 33L, 42L, 21L, 
50L, 37L, 56L, 23L, 34L, 26L, 53L, 19L, 36L, 32L, 44L, 21L, 38L, 
27L, 49L, 18L, 41L, 34L, 58L, 26L, 37L, 25L, 40L, 21L, 44L, 17L, 
51L, 16L, 51L, 24L, 32L, 22L, 34L, 21L, 37L, 20L, 44L, 10L, 36L, 
18L, 59L, 21L, 35L, 13L, 46L, 12L, 44L, 29L, 49L, 21L, 36L, 18L, 
47L, 19L, 41L, 21L, 29L, 23L, 40L, 20L, 39L, 21L, 38L, 4L, 41L, 
30L, 54L, 21L, 30L, 22L, 56L, 24L, 19L, 16L, 49L, 25L, 34L, 22L, 
54L, 20L, 33L, 14L, 40L, 10L, 37L, 14L, 43L, 23L, 27L, 30L, 40L, 
22L, 34L, 19L, 37L, 23L, 32L, 19L, 37L, 26L, 35L, 11L, 37L, 31L
), meps_labels = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Albany", "Albuquerque", "Amarillo", 
"Anchorage", "Atlanta", "Baltimore", "Beckley", "Boise", "Boston", 
"Buffalo", "Butte", "Charlotte", "Chicago", "Cleveland", "Columbus", 
"Dallas", "Denver", "Des Moines", "Detroit", "El Paso", "Fargo", 
"Fort Dix", "Fort Jackson", "Fort Lee", "Harrisburg", "Honolulu", 
"Houston", "Indianapolis", "Jackson", "Jacksonville", "Kansas City", 
"Knoxville", "Lansing", "Little Rock", "Los Angeles", "Louisville", 
"Memphis", "Miami", "Milwaukee", "Minneapolis", "Montgomery", 
"Nashville", "New Orleans", "New York", "Oklahoma City", "Omaha", 
"Phoenix", "Pittsburgh", "Portland, ME", "Portland, OR", "Raleigh", 
"Sacramento", "Salt Lake City", "San Antonio", "San Diego", "San Jose", 
"San Juan", "Seattle", "Shreveport", "Sioux Falls", "Spokane", 
"Springfield", "St. Louis", "Syracuse", "Tampa"), class = "factor"), 
    RR = c(56, 100, 81, 73, 26, 76, 78, 83, 15, 88, 93, 91, 12, 
    94, 82, 55, 31, 91, 83, 86, 22, 86, 41, 83, 24, 92, 87, 100, 
    50, 88, 68, 90, 32, 100, 65, 83, 49, 91, 59, 100, 81, 100, 
    65, 81, 93, 94, 47, 75, 84, 96, 69, 68, 85, 100, 59, 90, 
    86, 100, 56, 72, 78, 90, 54, 69, 70, 83, 39, 93, 63, 100, 
    47, 100, 64, 95, 46, 95, 76, 100, 42, 85, 87, 100, 42, 100, 
    83, 97, 37, 86, 83, 95, 43, 79, 79, 100, 37, 52, 82, 86, 
    44, 0, 70, 93, 32, 20, 92, 93, 51, 17, 63, 87, 12, 77, 79, 
    95, 81, 0, 94, 58, 92, 0, 77, 82, 92, 0), Time = structure(c(15614, 
    15614, 15614, 15614, 15645, 15645, 15645, 15645, 15675, 15675, 
    15675, 15675, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15706, 15737, 15737, 15737, 
    15737, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15765, 15796, 15796, 15796, 15796, 
    15826, 15826, 15826, 15826, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15857, 15887, 
    15887, 15887, 15887, 15918, 15918, 15918, 15918, 15949, 15949, 
    15949, 15949, 15979, 15979, 15979, 15979, 16010, 16010, 16010, 
    16010, 16040, 16040, 16040, 16040, 16071, 16071, 16071, 16071, 
    16102, 16102, 16102, 16102, 16130, 16130, 16130, 16130, 16161, 
    16161, 16161, 16161, 16191, 16191, 16191, 16191, 16222, 16222, 
    16222, 16222, 16252, 16252, 16252, 16252, 16283, 16283, 16283, 
    16283, 16314, 16314, 16314, 16314, 16344, 16344, 16344, 16344, 
    16375, 16375, 16375, 16375, 16405, 16405, 16405, 16405, 16436, 
    16436, 16436, 16436, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16467, 16495, 16495, 
    16495, 16495, 16526, 16526, 16526, 16526), class = "Date"), 
    Year = c("2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
    "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
    "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
    "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
    "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015")), .Names = c("SurveyID", 
"MEPSID", "ServiceID", "SurveyReturnedYear", "SurveyReturnedMonth", 
"CompletedSurvey", "TotalSurvey", "meps_labels", "RR", "Time", 
"Year"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
521L, 522L, 523L, 524L, 781L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 1041L, 1042L, 
1043L, 1044L, 1301L, 1302L, 1303L, 1304L, 1561L, 1562L, 1563L, 
1564L, 1821L, 1822L, 1823L, 1824L, 2081L, 2082L, 2083L, 2084L, 
2341L, 2342L, 2343L, 2344L, 2601L, 2602L, 2603L, 2604L, 2861L, 
2862L, 2863L, 2864L, 3121L, 3122L, 3123L, 3124L, 3381L, 3382L, 
3383L, 3384L, 3641L, 3642L, 3643L, 3644L, 3901L, 3902L, 3903L, 
3904L, 4161L, 4162L, 4163L, 4164L, 4421L, 4422L, 4423L, 4424L, 
4681L, 4682L, 4683L, 4684L, 4941L, 4942L, 4943L, 4944L, 5201L, 
5202L, 5203L, 5204L, 5461L, 5462L, 5463L, 5464L, 5721L, 5722L, 
5723L, 5724L, 5981L, 5982L, 5983L, 5984L, 6241L, 6242L, 6243L, 
6244L, 6501L, 6502L, 6503L, 6504L, 6761L, 6762L, 6763L, 6764L, 
7021L, 7022L, 7023L, 7024L, 7281L, 7282L, 7283L, 7284L, 7541L, 
7542L, 7543L, 7544L, 7801L, 7802L, 7803L, 7804L), class = "data.frame")
```

And the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)


p<- ggplot(data=df[df$MEPSID==1,],
           aes(x=Time, y=RR, colour=ServiceID, group=ServiceID, label=round(RR)))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 10))+
  labs(y="Response Rate")+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 110))+
  geom_line(size=.5)+
  geom_point()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green4","blue4","red4","dodgerblue"))+
  ggtitle("Counts")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=18, face="bold", vjust=1),
        axis.title=element_text(size=16),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, angle=90),
        axis.line=element_line(colour="black", size=.2),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        legend.margin=unit(-0.6, "cm"),
        legend.position="none",
        legend.text=element_text(size=14),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y=element_line(colour="gray", linetype="solid", size=.2))+ # or theme_blank())
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%b"), breaks=date_breaks("month"))+
  facet_grid(~Year, scales="free", space="free")


p2<-ggplot(df[df$MEPSID==1,], aes(x = Time, y = ServiceID, label=format(round(RR), nsmall=0), colour = ServiceID)) +
  geom_text(size = 3.5) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    plot.margin = unit(c(-0.5,1, 0, 0.5), "lines")) +
  xlab(NULL) + 
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_date(labels=c(), breaks=date_breaks("month"), expand=c(0.05,0.05))+
  facet_grid(~Year, scales="free", space="free_x")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(levels(df$ServiceID)))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("green4","blue4","red4","dodgerblue"))

grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(p,p2, 
                         nrow=2, heights=c(5,1)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to adjust text using `hjust` argument as an `aes`. But first you should add it to the data as its own column that you will pass into the `ggplot` command :

```
library(data.table)
DX <- setDT(df[df$MEPSID==1,])
DX[,hjust:=ifelse(Time==min(Time),0.1,ifelse(Time==max(Time),0.8,0.4)),Year] #This creates a new variable called hjust

p2<-ggplot(DX, 
           aes(x = Time, y = ServiceID, label=format(round(RR), nsmall=0), 
               colour = ServiceID,hjust=hjust)) +
    ## the rest of the plot 2
```

[image]

### add some explanation:

Here you are plotting a text using (Time versus ServiceID) by year. 
Since we want to shift our text horizontally, we will do it according to the value of Time (x-coordinate). More precisely, will just shift left-points to the right and right-points to the left. This will be done by setting a different hjust value for each group of values ( left vs right).

So for each year( each facet ) ,  I will horizontally adjust the points corresponding to the min of Time ( the extreme left points  of the facets), and the max of time ( the extreme right points of the facets). No need to adjust other points even I do it here.

```
 DX[,hjust:=ifelse(Time==min(Time),0.1,    ## extreme left point
            ifelse(Time==max(Time),0.8,    ## extreme right points
             0.4)),                        ## others 
             Year]                         ## for each facet
```

You can do the trsnformation in base R using `ave`:

```
ave(as.numeric(xx$Time),xx$Year,
    FUN=function(x)
      ifelse(x==min(x),0.1,ifelse(x==max(x),0.8,0.4)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing? I am not familiar with what is taking place here -- not sure what you mean by adding it to the data?

Comment: @vashts85 I add some explanation. I hope it is clear ( I am not really good in this exercise)

Comment: What does the `:=` mean?

Comment: it is a `data.table` operator. You should read the [package help](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) to get more details.

Comment: Got it, I will take a look. Is there a way to carry out the procedure you did with `data.table` but instead just use the base package? I have tried using `apply` or `ave` but can't get either to work.

Comment: THANK YOU!! This was immensely helpful as this is (a) answered my original question and (b) helped me learn the `ave` function and the `hjust` parameter!

Answer (score 9):

You can use `geom_blank` to fine-tune facetted scales.

```
grid.arrange(p + geom_blank(data = data.frame(Time = as.Date(c("2012-09-20", "2012-12-15", 
                                                               "2014-12-20", "2015-04-10")), 
                                              RR = 1:4, 
                                              Year = c(2012, 2012, 2015, 2015)),
                            aes(colour = NULL, group = NULL, label = NULL)) ,
             p2 + geom_blank(data = data.frame(Time = as.Date(c("2012-09-20", "2012-12-15", 
                                                                "2014-12-20", "2015-04-10")), 
                                               ServiceID = 1:4, 
                                               Year = c(2012, 2012, 2015, 2015)),
                             aes(colour = NULL, group = NULL, label = NULL)) , 
             nrow=2, heights=c(5,1))
```

[image: resulting plot]